# Make two divs fill up entire page space while keeping vertical scroll

Tags: html, css

I have four divs, three of which are in the right position so far, but one div doesn't want to cooperate with me. Here's a diagram:

[image: Div setup diagram]

How would I go about making the blue div fill up the entire space of the red div?

This is what I want it to look like:

[image]

The red div has this css to make it have a scroll wheel when necessary:

```css
.thread-container {
    flex-grow: 1;
    overflow-y: scroll;
    position: relative;
}
```

The blue div has this css:

```css
.thread-container .thread {
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    min-height: 800px;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: flex-end;
    color: #b3b2ca;
    background: #dcddf5;
}
```

I tested out adding `height: 100%;` to the blue div, but that made the div unable to scroll vertically.

If necessary, here is the css for the green div:

```css
.message-input {
    background: white;
    color: #484d79;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    height: 10vh;
    max-height: 65px;
}
```

By the way, I'm working with React here.

Thanks for reading!
~ Matthew

Comment: It's not clear why you would want your div to be scrollable if its content should be as high as the div itself. Do you want the blue div to take up all the space or more? in that case set the min-height:100%; instead of height itself.

Comment: Please provide a minimal, runnable snippet :) https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do

Comment: @Stackerexp Wow, I can't believe I overlooked that simple fix. Using min-height:100% worked for me. Thanks!